# Is a conditional function definition allowed in POSIX compliant shell scripts?

Tags: shell, posix

In Bash and [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (ksh), I see the following script works fine.

```
if [ -n "foo" ]
then
    foo()
    {
        echo function foo is defined
    }
else
    bar()
    {
        echo function bar is defined
    }
fi

foo
bar
```

It also generates the expected output when executed.

```
$ bash scr.sh
function foo is defined
scr.sh: line 15: bar: command not found

$ ksh scr.sh
function foo is defined
scr.sh: line 15: bar: not found
```

I want to know if this script would run and generate this output on any POSIX conformant shell.

Comment: POSIX shell does not exist. It is some different shell, run in POSIX compatibility mode. Yet with its own minor quirks and incompatibilities. Test additionally under the `ash` and `dash`, and if it works, then you are good to go. The four - ash, dash, bash & ksh - are what used to emulate the POSIX shell on various *NIX systems. All other Bourne shell emulate one of the four.

Comment: @Dummy00001 I didn't claim there is such a thing as "POSIX shell". I mean to ask if this code is guaranteed to run in any "POSIX compliant shell" as defined in the POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01 . I don't care about the test results from specific shells such as `dash`, `ash`, etc. What I care about is whether the script I wrote is syntactically valid as per the shell command language defined in the POSIX standard.

Comment: @Dummy00001 To be more specific, the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) in the syntax seems to indicate that `function_definition` is a `command` is a `pipe_sequence` is a `pipeline` is an `and_or` is a `term` is a `compound_list` and thus should be allowed in `if_clause`. Therefore, the answer to my question seems to be "Yes". But I would like to confirm this with those who are more skilled at reading the shell grammar than I am.

Comment: I've never read the grammar, but for a decade or so did make portable shell scripts. What I have told you in the comment above is the essence of that experience: forget about the POSIX shell, and test on the shells which are actually used to simulate the POSIX shell. Developers of the shells rarely care about POSIX compatibility - but instead about the compatibility between the Bourne shells. If it doesn't help, then sorry, wait for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your reading of the grammar. A function definition may occur in the body of an `if` statement, making its execution conditional.